# React displaying Flask image as byte code instead of image

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I have been prototyping a web server using flask and recently switched to ReactJS for my front end. I am trying to display an image that is stored on my server to my web page as follows:

```
@app.route("/graph" methods=['POST'])
def displayGraph():
    return send_from_directory("graphDir", "graph.png")
```

Before switching to React, if I went to /graph, the image would display no problem. Now, however, the webpage never redirects to `/graph` and displays the byte code for the image instead of the image itself. What do I need to change to properly display my image on my React web page? For reference, my React code is below:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    //Initialize your state here
    this.state = {
       results: "",
    };

    //bind functions here
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

//this is called after everything is created
componentDidMount() {

}

//add functions here
//changes state of checkbox
handleChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: value
    });
}

submit() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/graph",
    });
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="big title">Title</div>
            <input type="button" onClick={() => this.submit()} value="Submit" className="button"/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get the byte code of the image using the ajax call, you can add an `<img>` to your render and set the src to the image's byte code.

```
<image src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + 'your-image-data'/>
```

Comment: I tried it this way but I changed it to `'data:image/png;base64...` and I am still getting just the byte code. Is there a different encoding for PNG files